# SQL Server : parse XML in field with unknown namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to parse XML from a column to add it to a view for reports but I don't know the namespace. It may be more complicated because the fields within the XML are only created once the field is used in the base application.
The pfm.Entity table that I'm trying to parse XML from the Custom# column from is structured with the following columns:

```
[RootId#] ,[Id#] ,[LastId#] ,[Guid#] ,[Custom#] ,[Type#]
```

My goal is to parse the XML contained within Custom# into columns so that I can join the table with others on the RootId# field. Below is the select statement I'm testing with:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as ns)  
    SELECT TOP (1000)
        Custom#.value('(/ns:Fields/ns:Field)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS xmlfield
    FROM 
        [SelectDb].[pfm].[Entity]
```

My guess is that I'll need to be selecting with something like below but that's throwing an error on the # character.

```
SELECT 
    Custom#.value('(/ns:Fields/ns:MarketingSrcPercentage_901419#)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS mktsrcp
```

Below is two examples of what the XML in the field can look like. Keep in mind that there are rows where this is NULL as well.

```
<Fields>
  <Field name="PurchaseDate_NJ#">6/11/2018</Field>
  <Field name="AddOrImpDate_NJ#">8/1/2018</Field>
  <Field name="AffidavitAddOrExcep_NJ#">nfui fevtt[th40thijfkrkl grwgr ijg rgmrk gmkmr pkgi</Field>
  <Field name="DateOfPropertyAcquisition_DC#">8/7/2018</Field>
  <Field name="AuthorizedAppointedAgent_PA#">NAME OF PERSON AUTHORIZED/APPONTED AGENT PROMPT BOX</Field>
  <Field name="SpouseWaivingMaritalRights_PA#">NAME OF SPOUSE WAIVING MARTIAL RIGHTS PROMPT BOX</Field>
  <Field name="PersonalFunds_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="Currency_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="CashiersCheck_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="TravelersCheck_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="MoneyOrder_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="BusinessCheck_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="PersonalCheck_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="BankruptcyFilings_NY#">true</Field>
</Fields>
```

and

```
<Fields>
  <Field name="">1</Field>
  <Field name="MarketingSrcPercentage_901419#">1</Field>
  <Field name="MarketingRep1Name_901419#">Brian</Field>
</Fields>
```

In case it's helpful, this is a database for SoftPro Select. I've looked through their documentation but I haven't found anything of help.

EDIT: Added in a clearer definition of the source table.

Answer (score 0):

The XML you provide does not include any namespace? I don't know, why you think you need `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` at all...

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Fields>
  <Field name="PurchaseDate_NJ#">6/11/2018</Field>
  <Field name="AddOrImpDate_NJ#">8/1/2018</Field>
  <Field name="AffidavitAddOrExcep_NJ#">nfui fevtt[th40thijfkrkl grwgr ijg rgmrk gmkmr pkgi</Field>
  <Field name="DateOfPropertyAcquisition_DC#">8/7/2018</Field>
  <Field name="AuthorizedAppointedAgent_PA#">NAME OF PERSON AUTHORIZED/APPONTED AGENT PROMPT BOX</Field>
  <Field name="SpouseWaivingMaritalRights_PA#">NAME OF SPOUSE WAIVING MARTIAL RIGHTS PROMPT BOX</Field>
  <Field name="PersonalFunds_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="Currency_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="CashiersCheck_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="TravelersCheck_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="MoneyOrder_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="BusinessCheck_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="PersonalCheck_TXFA#">true</Field>
  <Field name="BankruptcyFilings_NY#">true</Field>
</Fields>';
```

--Just some examples to get your named values in a type-safe way.
--The rest works the same...

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/Fields/Field[@name="PurchaseDate_NJ#"])[1]','date') AS [PurchaseDate_NJ#]
      ,@xml.value('(/Fields/Field[@name="AuthorizedAppointedAgent_PA#"])[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [AuthorizedAppointedAgent_PA#]
      ,@xml.value('(/Fields/Field[@name="Currency_TXFA#"])[1]','bit') AS [Currency_TXFA#]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I wasn't clear. The XML is already defined in a column named Custom# in a table name pfm.Entity and is put there by an application. The table has the following columns:
[RootId#] ,[Id#] ,[LastId#] ,[Guid#] ,[Custom#] ,[Type#]

Comment: @user11209799 It should be enough to use your column's name instead of `@xml`. Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the problem but not the ideal solution which would pull all fields and sort them into columns. I'm still looking for the namespace but the below is working for now.

```
SELECT TOP (1000)
    entity.Custom#.value('data(//Field[@name="MarketingRep1Name_901419#"])[1]','VARCHAR(100)') 'MarketingRep1'
FROM 
    [SelectDb].[pfm].[Entity] entity
```